# cypress-grep has been broken when migrate to Cypress 10

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I was using grepOmitFiltered option on cypress-grep. cypress-grep working like grepOmitFiltered: false, it is reading my all spec files since I have upgraded the project to Cypress 10. Here is my cypress.config.ts file. Could you support me with this issue?

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: '22eajy',
  reporter: 'cypress-multi-reporters',
  viewportWidth: 1280,
  viewportHeight: 720,
  reporterOptions: {
    configFile: 'reporter-config.json',
  },
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,
  videoUploadOnPasses: false,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  retries: 3,
  env: {
    grepOmitFiltered: true,
  },
  video: true,
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('cypress-grep/src/plugin')(on, config)
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  },
})
```

Return this error:

```html
Warning: We failed to trash the existing run results.

This error will not alter the exit code.

Error: spawn /Users/erdinc.ramanli/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.1.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/trash/lib/macos-trash EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```